# ACCESS LEFT JOIN with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I'd like to do something like this:

`SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id AND t1.field1=false`

So, I don't want to see data from `t2` table for those records from `t1` table where `t1.field1=false`.
It's possible in ORACLE, but is this possible in MS ACCESS?

Edit: I got `Syntax error in JOIN operation` and `JOIN expression not supported` and `Invalid argument to function`.

Edit2: To prevent further misunderstanding and "put in the `WHERE` clause" comments.
[image: <code>t1</code> table]
[image: <code>t2</code> table]

`SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id`
[image: simple <code>LEFT JOIN</code>]

If you write my very first `SELECT` in ORACLE, you will see this (and I have to do it in MS). I want to see ALL records from `t1` table, but I don't want to join every record, but only where `t1.f1=false`. You can see that where `id=2` and `id=5`. 
[image: how it works in ORACLE but not in MS]

Comment: Your query would only show entries, where field1 IS false. (If it was valid at all) Have you tried `SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id WHERE t1.field1!=false`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access SQL LEFT JOIN alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897998/access-sql-left-join-alternative)

Comment: Well maybe it's different for MS Access, but at least a wrong logic won't cause errors. Since you are working with an abstract example here - do you maybe have reserved keywords as table/column name? (If so, wrap them with `[ ]`)

Comment: @dognose I just tested on ORACLE and it's working like I thought and want but MS is useless like always. And no, I don't use reserved words.

Comment: To all commenters - MS Access doesn't support constants in joins.

Comment: I can't write good answer - I have no documentation to support my claim :( I concluded this just from experience. And I don't hate MS :)

Comment: @Arvo, what do you mean by 'constants' in this case? What am I missing?

Comment: @June7 `false` is a constant. I could write something like `t1.field1=t2.field2`, and it would work.

Comment: @Arvo, Ooops, I was thinking about WHERE clause, not the bizarre  JOIN attempted by poster which I just realized upon re-reading post. So, I agree with you. And a WHERE clause is probably what is needed, not the AND operator.

Comment: answered in prior question here?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015878/left-joining-on-additional-criteria-in-ms-access

Comment: @xQbert Unfortunately no, my question is different, see `t1.field1=false`, not `t2.field1=false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the desired result with multiple `SELECT`, which is disgusting, if you have a long and multiple `SELECT` in the first place.

`SELECT t1.*, a.c1
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.*
                  FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
                  WHERE t1.f1=false) AS a
ON t1.id=a.id`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply a filter to the dataset, try using WHERE in place of AND in your query.

`SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id WHERE t1.field1=False`

Answer (score 1):

This simpler solution works for me:

```sql
SELECT t2.*, falset1.c1
FROM t2 LEFT JOIN (SELECT t1.*
                    WHERE t1.f1=false) AS falset1
ON t2.id=falset1.id
```

Basically you subset the data that needs a constant with the `where` clause and then use that subset in the `left join`